# How to access internet from QEMU?

Tags: windows, linux, networking, qemu

I am running qemu version 0.13 on windows XP. My Host OS is Windows XP and my guest OS is Debian 4(Etch). How do I connect to internet from Debian OS? My windows OS can connect to Internet. The following is the launching command which I am using now to launch qemu in windows XP. Please help me on this issue.

```
qemu\qemu.exe -L "qemu" -boot c  -hda  "debian4.img" -m 512  -localtime -ctrl-grab -usb -net nic,model=ne2k_pci,macaddr=52:54:00:12:34:56 -net user -redir udp:161::161 -redir tcp:4440::22
```

Comment: not a programming question, should be on serverfault

Comment: You need to set up an internal bridge. At least on Linux that's how you do it. I'm not sure how to do that on Windows, or if it's even possible.

Comment: @Keith: Can you explain how it is possible atleast in Linux?

Comment: Nothing against qemu, but you might want to give VirtualBox a try instead. It's very beginner friendly.

Comment: See if the [Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking) helps you out.

Answer (score 7):

Delete the options about the network, like:

```
-net nic,model=ne2k_pci,macaddr=52:54:00:12:34:56 -net user -redir udp:161::161 -redir tcp:4440::22
```

qemu has default network configurations, and is able directly to access www.

Comment: without `-net nic` it doesn't work - with `-net nic -net user` it does work :)